# jQuery to check if returned data object is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```
$("#post").live("click",function()
{
    $("input:checkbox[name='bookmarkid']:checked").each(function()
    {
         $.post("php/socialbookmark-post.php", {bookmarkID: $(this).val()},function(data)
         {
              if(data != "") alert(data);
         });
    });
});
```

the php file outputs some text only if something goes wrong. The checking that I do fails if the data is empty and displays an empty message. I need to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

You could instead check if data exists, like this:

```
if(data && data !="") alert(data);
```

`data` will be `null` in your case, and `null != ""`, so the `if` is passing.

Comment: still having the same problem. must be some other way of checking....or could you post how to check if a specific string is in the return data? That would solve things instead of checking whether it's empty or not.

Comment: @user253530  - If you do `alert(data.length);` what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If data is empty then condition for check `data !== ''` it will generate false

```
if(data !== 'undefined' && data !== ''){
console.log('data is not empty')
} else {
console.log('data is empty')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue. The data block will not execute of if data not returned from ajax. But find a way to solved by referring jQuery Ajax documents:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

By the implementation we have used the sucess method of done and if data not returned it will not executed. Instead fail method will get called. Refer to

```
fail(function())
```